# Win Explorer shortcut to expand folder in navigation pane

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

Is there a shortcut ( or a setting ) to expand the navigation pane folders to the currently open folder in the right pane ?
I seem to recall Win2K and maybe XP era explorer did that automatically, but not in Win7.
Clicking expand arrows on folders on the left one by one gets me there, but there surely must be a faster way ?

Comment: Do you have this set? Go to "Organise" menu select "Folder Options" (or tools menu, Folder options). In the "General" tab look in the "Navigation Pane" section for [x] Automatically Expand to Current Folder.

Comment: Yes now i do, and it does exactly what i needed. As it happens it occured to me to look there right after i posted the question.
I'll leave the question open - maybe there is a shortcut key too.

Comment: You could right-click anywhere on the navigation pane to enable that setting too.

Answer (score 7):

The shortcut key to expand the navigation pane to the current folder is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: That doesn't work on Windows 7 (which is the OP's Operating System).

Comment: It works on my system (Windows 7 Professional SP1 x64).

Comment: Hmm. Here the cursor just jumps to another entry on the nav pane on  Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 x64. I can't think why explorer would behave differently for different version of Windows 7 ...

Comment: Are you looking in the Navigation pane?

Comment: Yes. I have a folder selected in the nav pane showing `+`. I type <ctrl>+<shift>+<e> and the selection moves downwards to some other folder, but no expansion occurs.

Comment: Before: https://i.imgur.com/Yg5qXDc.png, after: https://i.imgur.com/ZV5TniK.png

Comment: The benefits can be seen only when one navigates to the folder without using the navigation pane (perhaps by clicking a folder in Favorites), then pressing Ctrl+Shift+E. It will expand to that folder in the Navigation pane.

Comment: Fair enough. Not a useful short cut then if it only works some of the time;)

Comment: I think you misunderstand David. Unless "Expand to open folder" is checked, the left side nav pane doesn't always sync to what is showing on the right (and to what is in the address bar.). Ctrl+Shift+E syncs the nav pane to the address bar. This is very useful to those of us who do not what "Expand to open folder" checked. Different people use explorer in very different ways.

Answer (score 3):

FYI – after you upgrade to Windows 8, there is a setting for what you need. See **Expand to open folder** in open menu on the left:

[image]